# Safari cannot download this file (Passbook Pass)

Tags: java, iphone, passbook, passkit

I am using passkit(java). i am created passes and try to install from safari.

when i am download passes from  mac mini safari, it download and show the passes.
but when download passes from iphone6 and iphone4 safari, it show error "safari cannot download this file".

i am also change htaccess.

You can access the pass here:
    `http://103.14.127.126/devesh/test.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pass bundle does not contain an icon.

```
Nov 28 17:34:28 pfr MobileSafari[2127] <Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass M5AULVCSR9.pass.egratify.gift/9128232779653468419. Pass does not contain icon.png/icon@2x.png/icon3x.png
Nov 28 17:34:28 pfr MobileSafari[2127] <Warning>: PassBook Pass download failed: The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.
```

You also should not be including your certificate in p12 or PEM format in the pass bundle.  I would strongly recommend that you revoke this certificate an reissue another.

[image]

Once you fix these, your pass will still fail to load because your pass.json has an `authenticationToken` key, but is missing a `webServiceURL`.  You should either add a valid `webServiceURL` or remove the `authenitcationToken` key.

Your final problem is the `passTypeIdentifier` key.  This should match the name of the certificate used to sign your pass.  In this case, `pass.egiftfy.giftCupon`.

```
{
    "formatVersion": 1,
    "serialNumber": "9128232779653468419",
    "passTypeIdentifier": "M5AULVCSR9.pass.egratify.gift",
    "authenticationToken": "1234567890987653",
    "description": "Devesh kumar",
    "teamIdentifier": "M5AULVCSR9",
    "organizationName": "OrgName",
    "logoText": "Devesh kumar ka pass",
    "foregroundColor": "rgb(255,255,255)",
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "barcode": {
        "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
        "message": "ABCDEFG",
        "messageEncoding": "UTF-8"
    },
    "storeCard": {
        "primaryFields": [{
            "key": "balance",
            "label": "balance",
            "value": "100",
            "currencyCode": "EUR"
        }]
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

You pass is still failing because the `passTypeIdentifier` does not match the certificate you have used to sign the pass.

```
Nov 28 19:14:33 pfr MobileSafari[2127] <Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass pass.egratify.gift/9128232779653468419. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.
```

Looking at your signature file in a hex editor, it looks like you are now signing with an App Developer certificate and not a Pass Type ID certificate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66210/discussion-on-answer-by-passkit-safari-cannot-download-this-file-passbook-pass).

Comment: @PassKit - Can you share with us how you manage to get those debug messages from MobileSafari ? - It would help others diagnose problems with their .pkpass files - Thanks!

Comment: Just hook your phone up to a Mac running Xcode and look in the console log for the device.